# How would you approach forms using stencil.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component, stenciljs

I'm looking to start using stencil.js for managing web components for a number of projects so that they're standard, consistent and maintainable. One question that came into my mind with this is how you would manage forms.

For example, typically, I would expect a component library to have form field components such as an input, select and textarea. However, [reading Stencil's docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/forms), it seems to suggest creating the complete forms as component - in my scenario, Angular would be the typical go to framework for this using Reactive Forms, does using stencil then mean I would create the complete form as a component and then reference this within my Angular component?

Is this a recommended approach and any more information around developers use of this would be great to here!

Comment: that is what the documentation says

Comment: If you are going to create "form components", either don't use shadow dom or slot any native form elements like input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Stencil to build the low-level components (input, checkbox etc.) and compose them in a Framework.

There are however [some gotchas regarding form elements and shadow dom](https://www.hjorthhansen.dev/shadow-dom-and-forms/).

- input fields inside the shadow dom will not be picked up by a form ancestor outside the shadow dom
- I remember hearing about some accessibility concerns, but I'm not certain

There are some ways to enable form participation (such as manually creating a hidden input as a sibling of the shadowed component), but just a couple days ago [Stencil published an update](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/pull/4784) including support for [`formAssociated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/attachInternals) which might be a better option (although ATM [the browser support is about 87%](https://caniuse.com/?search=attachInternals))

Since Stencil was created for use by the Ionic Framework team, I always suggest looking at their implementation for inspiration/best practice (e.g. [input component](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/main/core/src/components/input/input.tsx)). They appear to disable shadow dom for form elements.

Some more links:

- [Form-associated custom elements](https://www.hjorthhansen.dev/shadow-dom-form-participation/)
- [open issue in Porsche Design System to use `formAssociated`](https://github.com/porsche-design-system/porsche-design-system/issues/2826)